# Floor plan in flutter

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to come up with best way to draw a floor plan in flutter, something like these images, but it would be for regals in one concrete shop, instead of plan of shopping centre with multiple shops.

[floor plan 1](https://www.thederwentgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/WTC-Site-Plan-First-Floor.png)
[floor plan 2](https://90percentofeverything.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/ikea2.gif)

i decided rectangles would be sufficient enough for now and i have multiple ideas on how to execute, but no idea which one is the best. or maybe there is even better one i have not thought of

**1. using custom painter**

regals have attributes: `ax, ay, bx, by`, so they go from point a (left bottom) to b (right upper)
code like this

```
final rect = Rect.fromPoints(
    Offset(regal.ax.toDouble(), size.height - regal.ay.toDouble()),
    Offset(regal.bx.toDouble(), size.height - regal.by.toDouble()),
);
```

this is good because it is flexible, there is pretty much unlimited range of options, but using `CustomPainter` is a bit buggy in my case, alongside with `Transform` and `GestureDetector` it bugs out sometimes and instead of clicking on "buttons" you need to track where user clicked, ehm, tapped.

**2. using gridView?**

i dont have thought this thru as much as first option, but big plus would be using styled buttons as regals, instead of rectangles.
possible problems would be button sizing, if one regal would be times bigger than others.

regal attributes would be `order on x axis, order on y axis, x flex (for example 3 as 3 times of base size), y flex`

i think i have not thought of the best solution yet.

what would it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quick playground using a `Stack` of `Regals` who are just `Containers` in this quick implementation under 250 lines of code.

[image]

Click the `FloatActionButton` to create random `Regal`. Then, you can define the position of each Regal and its Size, within the limit of the Floor Plan and Max/min Regal Size.

In this quick implementation, the position of a Regal can be defined both with Gestures or Sliders; while its size can only be defined using the sliders.

### Package Dependencies

- [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) ([Flutter Hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) flavor) for State Management
- [Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) for Domain classes immutability

### Full Source Code (222 lines)

```dart
import 'dart:math' show Random;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

part '66478145.floor_plan.freezed.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final regals = useProvider(regalsProvider.state);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                    width: kFloorSize.width,
                    height: kFloorSize.height,
                    color: Colors.amber.shade100),
                ...regals
                    .map(
                      (regal) => Positioned(
                        top: regal.offset.dy,
                        left: regal.offset.dx,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          child: RegalWidget(regal: regal),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
            RegalProperties(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => context.read(regalsProvider).createRegal(),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RegalWidget extends HookWidget {
  final Regal regal;

  const RegalWidget({Key key, this.regal}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _previousOffset = useState<Offset>(null);
    final _refOffset = useState<Offset>(null);
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => context.read(selectedRegalIdProvider).state = regal.id,
      onPanStart: (details) {
        _previousOffset.value = regal.offset;
        _refOffset.value = details.localPosition;
      },
      onPanUpdate: (details) => context.read(regalsProvider).updateRegal(
            regal.copyWith(
                offset: _previousOffset.value +
                    details.localPosition -
                    _refOffset.value),
          ),
      child: Container(
        width: regal.size.width,
        height: regal.size.height,
        color: regal.color,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RegalProperties extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final regal = useProvider(selectedRegalProvider);
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: regal == null
          ? Text('Click a Regal to start')
          : Form(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text('WIDTH'),
                  Slider(
                    min: kRegalMinSize.width,
                    max: kRegalMaxSize.width,
                    value: regal.size.width,
                    onChanged: (value) => context
                        .read(regalsProvider)
                        .updateRegal(
                          regal.copyWith(size: Size(value, regal.size.height)),
                        ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  Text('HEIGHT'),
                  Slider(
                    min: kRegalMinSize.height,
                    max: kRegalMaxSize.height,
                    value: regal.size.height,
                    onChanged: (value) => context
                        .read(regalsProvider)
                        .updateRegal(
                          regal.copyWith(size: Size(regal.size.width, value)),
                        ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  Text('LEFT'),
                  Slider(
                    min: 0,
                    max: kFloorSize.width - regal.size.width,
                    value: regal.offset.dx,
                    onChanged: (value) =>
                        context.read(regalsProvider).updateRegal(
                              regal.copyWith(
                                  offset: Offset(value, regal.offset.dy)),
                            ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  Text('TOP'),
                  Slider(
                    min: 0,
                    max: kFloorSize.height - regal.size.height,
                    value: regal.offset.dy,
                    onChanged: (value) =>
                        context.read(regalsProvider).updateRegal(
                              regal.copyWith(
                                  offset: Offset(regal.offset.dx, value)),
                            ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}

final selectedRegalIdProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => null);

final selectedRegalProvider = Provider<Regal>((ref) {
  final selectedId = ref.watch(selectedRegalIdProvider).state;
  final regals = ref.watch(regalsProvider.state);
  return regals.firstWhereOrNull((regal) => regal.id == selectedId);
});

final regalsProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<RegalsNotifier>((ref) => RegalsNotifier());

class RegalsNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Regal>> {
  final Size floorSize;
  final Size maxSize;

  RegalsNotifier({
    this.floorSize = const Size(600, 400),
    this.maxSize = const Size(100, 100),
    List<Regal> state,
  }) : super(state ?? []);

  void createRegal() {
    state = [...state, Regal.random];
    print(state.last);
  }

  void updateRegal(Regal updated) {
    state = state.map((r) => r.id == updated.id ? updated : r).toList();
  }
}

@freezed
abstract class Regal implements _$Regal {
  const factory Regal({
    String id,
    Color color,
    Offset offset,
    Size size,
  }) = _Regal;

  static Regal get random {
    final rnd = Random();
    return Regal(
      id: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
      color: Color(0xff555555 + rnd.nextInt(0x777777)),
      offset: Offset(
        rnd.nextDouble() * (kFloorSize.width - kRegalMaxSize.width),
        rnd.nextDouble() * (kFloorSize.height - kRegalMaxSize.height),
      ),
      size: Size(
        kRegalMinSize.width +
            rnd.nextDouble() * (kRegalMaxSize.width - kRegalMinSize.width),
        kRegalMinSize.height +
            rnd.nextDouble() * (kRegalMaxSize.height - kRegalMinSize.height),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// CONFIG
const kFloorSize = Size(600, 400);
const kRegalMinSize = Size(10, 10);
const kRegalMaxSize = Size(200, 200);
```